# Create a json array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects like this below,

```
var A = [
    {
        "111": ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    {
        "222": ["D", "E", "F"]
    }
];
```

I would like to create a new array dynamically in the format as shown below using js or jQuery.

key in array A should be mapping to attribute text of AA and value should be to children as given below

```
var AA = [
    {
    "text": "111",
    "state": "open",
    "children": [
    {
        "text": "A"
    }, 
    {
        "text": "B"
    }, 
    {
        "text": "C"
    }]
}, 
{
    "text": "222",
    "state": "open",
    "children": [
    {
        "text": "D"
    }, 
    {
        "text": "E"
    }, 
    {
        "text": "F"
    }]
}];
```

How can I accomplish this ? Any thoughts would be helpful

Thanks for all of your suggestions and help.
But Right now I would like to change variable A and input in the format below,
how can i accomplish the same as before.

```
var A = {"1":["1_1","1_2","1_3"],
         "2":["2_1","2_2"],
         "3":["3_1"],
         "4":["4_1"],
         "5":["5_1","5_2"]};
```

Comment: firstly, don't think of it as JSON ... because it isn't ... think of it as creating a javascript object ... because that's what it is ... then, any beginner javascript tutorial should enlighten you

Comment: @JaromandaX JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: @aswzen - really? and the relevance of that is?

Comment: @RamRavi I answered the question in a very simple and straight forward way, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map `A` to `AA` using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (twice).

```
var AA = A.map(function(item) {
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; // this will be reliable only because each item has one property.
    return {
        'text': key,
        'state': 'open',
        'children': item[key].map(function(child) {
            return { 'text': child };
        })
    };
});
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khmkxz42/)**

Comment: No worries. Good luck with it.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I would like to change it to an obj instead of array like below,                                                           
  var A = { "1":["1_1","1_2","1_3"],
                 "2":["2_1","2_2"],
                 "3":["3_1"],
                 "4":["4_1"],
                 "5":["5_1","5_2"] };                                                                   
  How can I create AA from above A?

Comment: Best not to augment a question after it's been answered. What you are asking now is different enough to warrant raising a new question.

Comment: Thats fine.. I'll raise a new req.

Comment: You can post a link to the new Q in the comments under the question above.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is too long, but its still understandable

```js
var A = [
    {"111":["A","B","C"]},
    {"222":["D","E","F"]}
];
console.log(A);
A = superGenerator(A);
console.log(A);

function superGenerator(data){
    var dataF = [];
    var children = [];
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        children[i] = [];
        for (var [key, val] of iterate_object(data[i])) {
            for (var j = val.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                children[i][j] = [];
                children[i][j] = {
                    text    : val[j]
                }
            };
        }

        dataF[i] = {
            text        : Object.keys(data[i])[0],
            state       : 'open',
            children    : children[i]
        }
    };
    return dataF;
}

function* iterate_object(o) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
        yield [keys[i], o[keys[i]]];
    }
}
```

You can try it by click Run,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var A = [
    {
        "111": ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    {
        "222": ["D", "E", "F"]
    }
];

var AA = A.map(item => {
  return {
    "text": Object.keys(item)[0],
    "state": "open",
    "children": item[Object.keys(item)[0]].map(elem => { return {"text": elem} })
  }
});

console.log(AA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` to iterate through your array, for each object, iterate all its keys and generate the corresponding object.

```js
var arr = [ { "111": ["A", "B", "C"] }, { "222": ["D", "E", "F"] } ],
    result = arr.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((r,k) => {
      return {
        text : k,
        state : 'open',
        children : o[k].map(text => ({text}))
      };
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```